# Yii php ajax Undefined variable: model

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

I'm still struggling with ajax form and Yii.
I got the error Undefined variable: model. My form is renderPartial by another view renderPartial itself by another view.

Here the details

in my POST Controller

```
public function actionViewComment()
    {   
        $post=$this->loadModel();
        $comment=new Comment;
        $this->renderPartial('_viewComment',array(
            'model'=>$post,
            'comment'=>$comment,
        ));

}
```

_viewcomment.php call the commment/_form.php

```
<?php $this->renderPartial('/comment/_form',array(
            'model'=>$comment,
        )); ?>
```

in the _form.php , the variable $model is accessible 
there is a button that call a jquery function send() when it is clicked

function send()
     {

```
   var data=$("#comment-form").serialize();


  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
    url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("post/Ajax"); ?>',
   data:data,
success:function(data){
                alert("Data Saved"); 
              },
   error: function(data) { // if error occured
         alert("Error occured.please try again");
         alert(data);
    },

  dataType:'html'
  });

}
```

The actionAjax of the post controller contains

```
public function actionAjax()
    {
if(isset($_POST['Comment']))
        {
           if($model->validate())
            {
               $model->save();
               return;
            }
        } 
     }
```

In action Ajax , I got  the error  Undefined variable: model.  I dont understand why?

If I use $model=new Comment;  the data is not saved because $model is empty

Can you explain?

by adding

```
$model=new Comment;
$model->attributes = $_POST["Comment"];
```

I go the following error

```
DbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 tbl_comment.status may not be NULL. The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO 'tbl_comment' ("author", "email", "url", "content", "create_time") VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2, :yp3, :yp4) (C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\db\CDbCommand.php:358)</p><pre>#0 C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\db\ar\CActiveRecord.php(1077): CDbCommand->execute()
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In your `actionAjax`, you have to create model object for `Comment`. You didn't create $mode but you are calling their functions.

```
public function actionAjax()
    {
        if(isset($_POST['Comment']))
        {
           $model=new Comment;
           $model->attributes = $_POST["Comment"];
           if($model->validate())
            {
               $model->save();
               echo "saved";
            }
            else
            {
               echo "Failed";
            }
        } 
     }
```

Comment: I did already but in this case, the data is not saved.  I looked to the firebug and data sent is empty. 

@kumar_v

Comment: So your post is empty?

Comment: No , it is not.  I can see in firebug that $_POST is equal to my data entered @kumar_v

Comment: The response is stil empty in firebug.  @kumar_v

Comment: try updated code. however you will get some response from ajax. so if you get failed, then validation failed. then check your model validation and data

Comment: @sanfisa Did you try? what is the output?

Comment: Yes, it sends data  but of course I have the integrity controller error because some fields are empty. SHould I do this for all the variable ?  $_post contains already the date  in json form why should I do it again?  @kumar_v

Comment: No.   $model->attributes = $_POST["Comment"]; will set data in model object. If not, then you have to set manually.

Comment: it works but I need to send all the data to get validation from the model. How can I send all the data in 1 command? $model=$_POST ?  @kumar_v

Comment: I update my post with the content of the error. @kumar_v

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47041/discussion-between-sanfisa-and-kumar-v)

Comment: have you fixed your problem?